# WebSphere Unmanaged queue MQSUB return 2019 error

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I am wondering if anyone is an expert on the unmanaged WebSpehre message queue that can help me. 
We have an application that does the following in the constructor: 1. MQCONN to a queue manager. 2. MQOPEN to open an unmanaged queue. 3. MQSUB to subscribe to a list of topics. In the MQSUB, the options I passed in are: "MQSO_CREATE | MQSO_RESUME | MQSO_DURABLE | MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING". The problem is that, in the list of the topics, some of them would fail the MQSUB call and return error 2019, while other topics would succeed. I am not very familiar with the WebSphere queue, but based on the articles I've read, this error means the Hobj passed in does not match with the original MQSUB handle. We have tried to reset the queue and after that we saw all the subscription succeeded. However, in the subsequent tests, we saw the same problem again. What puzzles me is that, if the Hobj does not match the orignal handle, (because the application did not exit cleanly, so the subscriptions have not been cleaned up), why some would succeed? Don't they share the same Hobj handle returned from the MQOPEN call? What is the right way to handle this situation? Should I save the Hobj handle in a config file after the MQOPEN call, and when the application runs again, read from the config file and pass in this same Hobj handle? Or there is a way to reset the subscription before I run MQSUB again? Will this cause any message lost? Your insight is greatly appreciated!

## Here is the code:

```
WebSphere_MQ_FrontEnd::WebSphere_MQ_FrontEnd(const CI_String& qMgr, // the queue manager of interested topics
                                               const CI_String& connectionName, // topic list
                                               const CI_String& qName, // the unmanaged queue that will hold the subscribed messages
                                                int debug  // debug flag. Default set to be off.
                                            ) 
    // new constructor
    // Add Debug flag
{
/*    tibrv_status status;
*/
   const char TOPIC_DELIM_DEFAULT = '|';

   /*   Declare MQI structures needed                                */
   MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor             */
      /** note, sample uses defaults where it can **/

   char topicsString[1024]        = "";


   //MQHCONN  Hcon;                   /* connection handle             */
   //MQHOBJ   Hobj;                   /* object handle                 */
   MQSD sd = {MQSD_DEFAULT};       /* Subscription Descriptor */
   MQMD md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};       /* Message Descriptor */
   MQOD     td = {MQOD_DEFAULT};         /* Object descriptor                      */

   //MQGMO gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};    /* get message options */
   MQLONG   O_options;              /* MQOPEN options                */
   MQLONG   C_options;              /* MQCLOSE options               */
   MQLONG   CompCode = 0;           /* completion code               */
   //MQLONG   OpenCode;               /* MQOPEN completion code        */

   MQLONG   Reason;                 /* reason code                   */
   MQLONG   OReason = 0;                 /* reason code for MQOPEN                  */
   MQLONG   CReason;                /* reason code for MQCONN        */

   MQLONG   O_CompCode = 0;             /* newton MQSUB completion code         */ 
   MQLONG   S_CompCode;             /* newton MQSUB completion code         */
   MQBYTE   buffer[65536];            /* message buffer                */
   MQLONG   buflen;                 /* buffer length                 */
   MQLONG   messlen;                /* message length received       */

   MQLONG   SubscribeReason[MAX_SUBSCRIPTIONS] = { -1 };   /* reason code */
   /* reason code */
   char     QMgr[50];               /* queue manager name            */
   char     ReasonString[10];       /* String for Reason Code           */
   MQCNO    ConnectOptions = { MQCNO_DEFAULT };

   ConnectOptions.Options = MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK;

   int      subidx = 0;

   char     subname[256];
   char     topicname[256];

   //char *   topicString = topicStringDefault;
   _debug = debug;
   _Hcon = MQHC_UNUSABLE_HCONN; /* connection handle                */
   _Hobj = MQHO_NONE;            /* subscription queue handle        */

   std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);
   if (debug) {
      //printf("Constructor start\n"); 
      std::cout <<  "Constructor start" << '\n';
   }


   /******************************************************************/
   /*                                                                */
   /*   Connect to queue manager                                     */
   /*                                                                */
   /******************************************************************/

   if ((qMgr.size()) < 0) {
        CI_ExError ex(MQ_EMISSINGARG, "qMgr");
      ex.chain(CI_EINVALID, qMgr.data()).throwThis();

   }

   // prepare the subscription topic list. passed in from connectionName argument
      if ( connectionName.size() <0 ) {  // is this the right way to handle the error?
        if (debug) {
            //printf("connection Name size < 0\n");
            std::cout << "connection Name size < 0" << '\n';
        }
        CI_ExError ex(MQ_EMISSINGARG, "connectionName");
      ex.chain(CI_EINVALID, connectionName.data()).throwThis();
    }

   strncpy(topicsString, connectionName.data(), 1024); // how many topics are we expecting?
   //_TopicStringList = NULL;
   str_split(topicsString, TOPIC_DELIM_DEFAULT, _TopicStringList);

    try {
      strncpy(QMgr, qMgr.data(), 50);

      if ( debug) {
        //printf("calling MQCONNX\n"); 
        //printf("    Manager: %s\n" , QMgr); 
        std::cout << "calling MQCONNX" << '\n';
        std::cout << "    Manager: " << QMgr << '\n';
      }
        //printf("    1Options: %s\n" , ConnectOptions.Options);
    /*  removed  printf("    2Options: %ld \n" , CompCode); */


      MQCONN(QMgr,                    /* queue manager                  */
            &_Hcon,                   /* connection handle              */
            &CompCode,               /* completion code                */
            &CReason);               /* reason code                    */




    /* report reason and stop if it failed     */
    if (CompCode == MQCC_FAILED)    {
        //printf("3MQCONN ended with reason code %d\n", CReason);
        std::cout << "3MQCONN ended with reason code " << CReason << '\n';
        sprintf(ReasonString, "%d",CReason);
        CI_ExError ex(MQ_CONNFAILED);
        ex.chain(MQ_REASON, ReasonString).throwThis();
    }
   } catch (CI_ExError& ex) {
         ex.chain(MQ_STOP).throwThis();
   }

   if ( debug ) {
        if (CompCode != MQCC_FAILED)
            //printf("CompCode in MQCONN is OK.\n"  );
            std::cout << "CompCode in MQCONN is OK." << '\n';

        //printf("passed MQCONN\n");
        std::cout << "passed MQCONN" << '\n';
    }
   /******************************************************************/
   /*                                                                */
   /*   Use parameter as the name of the target queue                */
   /*                                                                */
   /******************************************************************/
   if ( debug ) {
        //printf("Checking qName %s is of size qName: \n",qName);
        std::cout << "Checking qName " << qName << " is of size qName:" << '\n'; 
   }
   if ((qName.size()) == 0) {
        CI_ExError ex(MQ_EMISSINGARG, "qName");
      ex.chain(CI_EINVALID, qName.data()).throwThis();
    }
    try {
        // try to open this unmanaged queue passed by user
        strncpy(od.ObjectName, qName.data(), (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);
        /*  removed   printf("target queue is %s\n", od.ObjectName); */
        MQLONG O_options = MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQOO_INQUIRE | MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
        if (debug ) {
        std::cout << "od: " << od.ObjectName << " O_options: " << O_options << " OReason:" << OReason<< '\n'; 
        }
        MQOPEN(_Hcon, &od, O_options, &_Hobj, &O_CompCode, &OReason); 
        if (O_CompCode != MQCC_OK)
        {
            //printf("MQOPEN ended with reason code %d\n", OReason);
            std::cout << "MQOPEN ended with reason code " << OReason << '\n';
        }

        if( debug ) {
            if (O_CompCode != MQCC_FAILED) {
                //printf("CompCode in MQOPEN is OK.\n"  );
                std::cout << "CompCode in MQOPEN is OK. Hobj: " << _Hobj << "\n";
            }

            //printf("passed MQOPEN\n");
            std::cout << "passed MQOPEN\n";

        }


    } catch (CI_ExError& ex) {
        /*  removed  cout << "called closed" << endl; */
         close();
         /*  removed  cout << "return from  closed" << endl;*/
         ex.chain(MQ_STOP).throwThis();
    }

    try {
        for (subidx = 0; *(_TopicStringList+subidx); subidx++) {
            sd.Options = MQSO_CREATE | MQSO_RESUME | MQSO_DURABLE | MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
            if (subidx > 0) 
            {
                sd.Options |= MQSO_SET_CORREL_ID;
                memcpy(sd.SubCorrelId, md.CorrelId, MQ_CORREL_ID_LENGTH);
            }

            sprintf(subname, "%s", _TopicStringList[subidx]);
            sprintf( topicname, "%s", strstr( subname, ":") + 1 );
            sd.ObjectString.VSPtr = topicname;
            sd.ObjectString.VSLength = MQVS_NULL_TERMINATED;
            sd.SubName.VSPtr = subname;
            sd.SubName.VSLength = MQVS_NULL_TERMINATED;
            if ( debug ) 
                //printf("Subscribe Topic String[%d]: %s\n", subidx, sd.ObjectString.VSPtr); 
                std::cout << "Subscribe Topic String[" << subidx << "]: \n subname:" << subname <<  " \n topic:" << topicname <<'\n';
            _Hsub[subidx] = MQSO_NONE;  

            MQSUB(_Hcon, &sd, &_Hobj, &_Hsub[subidx], &CompCode, &SubscribeReason[subidx]);
            if (CompCode != MQCC_OK)    { 
                //printf("MQSUB(%d) ended with reason code %d\n", subidx, SubscribeReason[subidx]);
                std::cout << "MQSUB(" << subidx << ") ended with reason code " << SubscribeReason[subidx] << '\n';

                }
            if (debug && CompCode == MQCC_OK)
                // printf( "passed MQSUB [%d]\n", subidx );
                std::cout << "passed MQSUB [" << subidx << "]\n";
            memcpy(md.CorrelId, sd.SubCorrelId, MQ_CORREL_ID_LENGTH);
        }
    } catch (CI_ExError& ex) {
        /*  removed  cout << "called closed" << endl; */
         close();
         /*  removed  cout << "return from  closed" << endl;*/
         ex.chain(MQ_STOP).throwThis();
   }
    if ( debug ) 
        //printf( "this is the End of Constructor\n" );
        std::cout << "this is the End of Constructor\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? That can help us better understand the problem. For unmanaged subscriptions, when calling MQSUB, a valid queue object handle is required. But definitely no need to save the Hobj to a config file.

Comment: Hi, Shashi, thanks for looking into my question! I have posted the code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for `MQSUB` returning 2019 is that application is passing the Hobj of a different queue than the one provided in the first `MQSUB` call. Pasting from KnowledgeCenter:

*If the Hobj is provided, it must be equivalent to the Hobj in the original MQSUB call. This means if an object handle returned from an MQOPEN call is being provided, the handle must be to the same queue as previously used. If it is not the same queue, the call fails with MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR.*

Can you check if you are passing the Hobj of the correct queue?

Comment: That is exactly my question. I saw this same message from KnowledgeCenter. I passed in the _hobj returned from the MQOPEN call in the same function, but I suspect the application bailed previously without unsubscribe, so maybe the connection did not clean up properly in the queue? But if that is the case, why some topic can still succeed the MQSUB call? Should I preserve the hobj in a file and restore the hobj the next time the application invoke the constructor?

Comment: No, it's not the Hobj (handle to queue) that you need to preserve. It's the name of the queue that needs to be preserved. When MQSUB is called next time, open the same queue and pass the Hobj returned to MQSUB call.

Comment: Yes, the queue name is read from a configuration file, so it is the same queue that has been passed in.

Comment: I think the question becomes this: if the subscriptions are durable, how to clean up the hanging subscriptions, or should the application finds out a way to resume the previous subscriptions.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce the 2019 error with a sample application. I can reproduce 2019 only when I pass a different subscription queue in subsequent MQSUB call, not the first MQSUB call.

Answer (score 0):

If the Hobj is provided on the `MQSUB` call it must represent the same queue as the subscription was originally made with. However, if you are resuming a subscription, even a non-managed one, there is no need to provide the Hobj, it will be returned to you by the MQSUB call.

I suspect the problem may be coming about because you have a single queue/Hobj for all your subscriptions but perhaps they weren't all made that way? You could discover which queues they are currently using by issuing `DISPLAY SUB` before running your application and comparing the output with the errors reported by your app.

You ask later how to ensure subscriptions are removed if they are left hanging. If the subscription should be removed any time an application closes, then just make them `MQSO_NON_DURABLE`. Doing this will mean you lose messages sent in the intervening time. If they should be resumed by another instance of the application which starts later and not have any gaps in the flow of messages from publishers, then leave them hanging and resume them.

I also see that your `subname` is based on the topicstring. Are there any duplicates in the list?

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights! No, there is no duplicates in the topic list. It is from a configuration file that we have full control. The design is to use one unmanaged queue to hold all the messages subscribed and the application cannot lose any message. I will pass your comments to our testing team.